# Reference request: how to check whether a set is invariant for a second order dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for some examples where invariant set is proved for second order systems

For a example, consider the Van Der Pol equation:
$$\dot x_1 = x_2$$
$$\dot x_2 = -x_1 + 0.5(1-x_1^2)x_2$$

In general, what is the procedure to prove that the solution is invariant with respect to

1. A "regular" set i.e. $D = \{(x_1, x_2)|x_1^2+ x_2^2 = 1\}$
2. A set with corners i.e. $D = \{(x_1, x_2)|x_1+ x_2 = 1\}$

Comment: If the set is $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\mid w(x_1,x_2)=c\}$, show that $w$ is constant along every solution of the system $\dot x_1=u(x_1,x_2)$, $\dot x_2=v(x_1,x_2)$, that is, $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}\,u+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}\,v=0.$$  A much more usual setting, though, is when $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\mid w(x_1,x_2)\leqslant c\}$, then it is enough to show that $$w(x_1,x_2)=c\implies\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}\,u+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}\,v\leqslant 0.$$